# how do I pass y to [y/n] kind of questions in linux automatically

Tags: linux, shell

I need to automate some installation, but in some commands it asks like 
"are you sure u want to continue[y\n]=?"
How do I always pass `y` to all such type of questions to automate my script?

```
echo 'y y y' | sudo rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

sudo yum install yum-plugin-replace

sudo yum replace mysql-libs --replace-with mysql55w-libs

sudo yum install mysql.`uname -i` yum-plugin-replace

echo yes "yes" | sudo yum install mysql55w mysql55w-server

sudo service mysqld start

sudo mysql_upgrade -u root
```

here is my shell script i need to execute it completely with out any such questions prompted.

Comment: The answer is `yes`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `yes` utility:

```
$ yes | sudo rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Comment: GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';  howdo i execute this command by using bash i tried using mysql-u -e"" but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Before resorting to the `yes` command (which risks giving y as an answer to things other than yes/no questions), read the documentation for the command you're using to see if it has an option to assume a "yes" answer to all (or most) interactive prompts.

I haven't used `rpm` much lately, but the `--force` option might be what you're looking for.